# Converting a string and an integer to a hex in smalltalk

Tags: string, hex, smalltalk, visualworks

***TL;DR: how do I convert ints into hex, also how would I convert a 1 character string into a Hex ( ie 'F' -> 0xF )***

looking to convert a character to a hex value, do some math, then convert back into a character.

so I have something like this:

```
addBits: aValue move: action
"aValue is always either 5 or 10 (0xA)"
"move is either 'a' for add or 's' for subtract"

|sum conversion|

"self stringToMakeHex is the string, it's always either an 'F', 'A', '0', 
or '5' I need to turn it into either 0xF,0xA,0x0,or 0x5"
conversion := (self stringToMakeHex) asInteger.

(action = 's')
ifTrue:[sum:= conversion - aValue.]
ifFalse:[sum:=conversion + aValue.].

stringToMakeHex: (sum asString).
```

I know I shouldn't be doing `asInteger`, as it converts 'F' into a zero somehow, so I'm wondering if there's a nice way to get 0xF or even 15 from it. My other problem is that aValue is coming in as an integer (5 and 10 base10) so I'll need a way to get the hex values 0x5 and 0xA.

All this data is retrieved via TCP/IP from a dif program so it's out of my control what format I receive... Doesn't help that I need to send back a string in order for the communication to be handled across the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(Compiler evaluate: '16r', self stringToMakeHex)
```

To convert back:

```
(sum printStringRadix: 16)
```

Comment: This was the best answer, quick and concise. worked like a charm

Answer (score 4):

In Pharo (and Squeak if I'm not mistaken) you can use the class side `#readFrom:base:` method of `Integer`: `Integer readFrom: self stringToMakeHex base: 16`.
This gives you an integer of value `15` in the case of `'F'`.

If I were you I'd encapsulate the reading and printing in a new class, e.g. `HexString`. You could implement `on:` on the class side and `+`, `-`, and `printOn:` on the instance side.

#### Update:

To get a `String` from an integer in a specific base use `#printStringBase:` (in Pharo) or `#printOn:base:` (which is probably more portable) like so: `12 printStringBase: 16`. This evaluates to `'C'`.

Comment: +1 on creating a class that does the Hex-stuff. In VisualWorks, if you want to print an integer as hex you can use #printOn:base:. To read an Integer from a hex-string you need to use #readFrom:radix: in VisualWorks. To implement a hex-class you should subclass Integer because a Hex-Number is still an Integer and you get all the arithmetics for free.

Comment: ok, so how would I get a string as the final product then? say I read in the 'F' convert to value of 15, subtract 5, and am left with 10. how am I to get 'A'